# Haskell perform function on list n number times

Tags: haskell

I am learning functional programming using Haskell. I am trying to create a function that takes a function `f`, and executes the function on some input `x`, `n` number of times.

```
(a -> a) -> a -> Int -> [a]
repeat f x n
```

So, the output list is like this:

```
[x, f(x), f(f(x)), ..., f^n(x)]
```

So far I have been able to come up with a function that I believe does this, but I don't know how to constrain it so it only performs n number of times:

```
fn f a = (f a) : (fn f (f a))
```

Could someone lend a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify two separate cases: one where recursion happens and the list continues, and another where recursion does not happen, and there needs to be some way to decide between the cases. The third parameter `n` looks like just the right thing for that:

```
fn f a 0 = []
fn f a n = f a : fn f (f a) (n-1)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to give another way (just for fun).

There is a very similar function: `scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]` in the library, it performs:

```hs
scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
```

which is quite similar to what you want to do.
So we can write:

```hs
fn :: (a -> a) -> a -> Int -> [a]
fn f a n = scanl (\x _ -> f x) a (replicate n ())

-- or you can write:
-- fn f a n = scanl (const . f) a (replicate n ())
```

In `(\x _ -> f x)` we discard the second parameter (which is the `()`).

Note how it works:

```hs
fn f a n == [a, (\x _ -> f x) a (), (\x _ -> f x) ((\x _ -> f x) a ()) (), ...]
         == [a, f a, f (f a), ...]
```

Comment: If you're going to use built-in functions, `take (n+1) (iterate f a)` seems simpler.

Comment: or in fact `take n $ fn f a`.